# how to post on linkedin via api using c#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I've developed code to post on linkedin, but it still gives me a 401 error even though I get permission.

I tried the steps on the linkedin share api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow) page, but I got stuck in step 4. Although I received acess token successfully, in step 4, he says that the access token is invalid.

```
using Nancy.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Linkedin_post
{
    public class PostLinkedin
{
    public string linkedinSharesEndPoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares";
    public string defaultUrl = "https://example.com/auth/callback";
    public string defaultImageUrl = "https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2018/05/17/you-can-train-your-cat/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.jpg";
    public bool PostLinkedInNetworkUpdate(string accessToken, string title, string submittedUrl, string submittedImageUrl)
    {
        submittedUrl = defaultUrl;
        submittedImageUrl = defaultImageUrl;
        var requestUrl = String.Format(linkedinSharesEndPoint, accessToken);
        var message = new
        {
            comment = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
            content = new Dictionary<string, string>
{   { "title", title },
    //{ "description", description},
    { "submitted-url", submittedUrl },
    {"submitted-image-url" , submittedImageUrl}
},

            visibility = new
            {
                code = "anyone"
            }
        };

        var requestJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);

        var client = new WebClient();
        var requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection
{

    {"Content-Type", "application/json" },
            {"x-li-format", "json" }

 };
          client.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
          var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
          var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson);
          return response.ContainsKey("updateKey");
    }
}
```

}

```
var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
```

returns a 401 error on this line of code.

Comment: WebClient is not really the advised way to go for HttpCalls in .NET. Have you tried doing your implementation using HttpClient and the Post method it contains ?